# Is it possible to use Husky + lint stages to check for Console.logs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, circleci

Just wondering if it’s possible to use husky/lint stages to check for console logs during a pre-commit and fail if there are console logs? I couldn’t find anything specific to console logs.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console ?

Comment: Did you check answers ? @Noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my vue project i am using like this.

eslintrc.js:

```js
    module.exports = {
      extends: ['./.eslintrc.js'], // it contains other rules
      rules: {
        'no-console': 'error',
      },
    };
```

huskyrc.js:

```js
    module.exports = {
      hooks: {
        'pre-commit': 'lint-staged'
      }
    }
```

and package json:

```json
    "scripts": {
      "lint:eslint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-path .eslintignore .",
    },
    "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": [
      "npm run lint:eslint"
    ],
  }
```

Edit: also you need install `"lint-staged"` package.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that helps anyone, but if you don't want to go through the hassle of a linter, there's a simple package.json trick.

I have husky running `pnpm precommit` as a hook. I run type checking and tests in there.

Well I just added a script:

```
"nologs": "[ $(git diff \"origin/$(git branch --show)\" | egrep '^[+]' | egrep 'console[.]log' | wc -l) -ge 1 ] && exit 10 || exit 0",
```

This will exit and prevent you to commit if you're adding "console.log" anywhere.

My precommit hook is then:

```
"precommit": "pnpm nologs && pnpm types && pnpm test"
```

This probably works with npm/yarn too provided a couple of tweaks.

My 2 cents ;)

Answer (score 0):

this will verify if has some console.log in your code.

in your .eslintrc put this guy

```
"no-console": "error",
```

and in the husky file:

```
 {
      "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
        "pre-push": "yarn test:coverage"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. in ***.eslintrc.js*** file:

```
    module.exports = {
      plugins: ["security"],
      rules: {
        "no-console": ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
        "no-debugger": ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off"
      }
    }
```

2. In `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file:

you can paste this code
https://gist.github.com/guilherme/9604324#file-gistfile1-sh

```
Difference is that you can commit *.eslintrc.js* file but *pre-commit* is only for you.
```